# VBA if statement to change group by of a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

looking to create a button that will change the pivot tables group by depending on what it is already currently grouped by. Here's what I have so far:

```
Range("EE6").Select    
If group Start:=40756 then
Selection.Group Start:=40695, End:=True, By:=7, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, False, False, False)
Else
Range("EE6").Select
Selection.Group Start:=40756, End:=True, By:=7, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, False, False, False)
End if
```

but I am getting Compile Error Expected: Then or Goto on the first line.
Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: that's not the correct way to get group http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55370

Comment: Actually the way I have it set up is the appropriate way to get the group of the proper pivot table. I have multiple pivot tables on one sheet in the workbook and the number associated to each pivot table is usually different, and therefore to specify the pivot table I am wanting to change the grouping of, I must use a cell selection.

Comment: exactly, a cell so, cell start wont work, nor will if group start=

Comment: so I'm not sure exactly what you are proposing to do for the solution then. Keep in mind I need this to first look at what the current group by selection is to determine which group by selection to make

Comment: `If group Start:=40756 then` - `Group` is a method of a `Range` object - it isn't a command that acts by itself.  That statement is like saying `If SaveAs Then`.

Comment: I see your point that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (assuming `EE6` is the cell that contains the first value of the group):

```
Dim startDate As Date
If Range("EE6").Value = "<01/08/2011" Then 'The date format may differ on your computer - use whatever is appropriate for you
    startDate = DateSerial(2011, 1, 6) 
Else
    startDate = DateSerial(2011, 1, 8)
End If

Range("EE6").Group Start:=startDate, End:=True, By:=7, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, False, False, False)
```

---

If you are actually trying to switch groupings between Monday start, and Wednesday start, try the following:

```
Dim startDate As Date
Dim tempVal As String
tempVal = Range("EE6").Value
If IsDate(tempVal) Then
    startDate = CDate(tempVal)
ElseIf InStr(tempVal, " - ") > 0 Then
    startDate = DateValue(Left(tempVal, InStr(tempVal, " - ") - 1))
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid data"
    Exit Sub
End If

If startDate Mod 7 = 2 Then
    startDate = 4
Else
    startDate = 2
End If
Range("EE6").Group Start:=startDate, End:=True, By:=7, Periods:=Array(False, False, _
        False, True, False, False, False)
```

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that date ranges in the pivot will always be greater than both the 06/01/2011 and 08/01/2011 start dates. I picked these dates cause they represent a Monday start and a Wednesday start, and I know that data will always come after these start dates.

Comment: So your question is actually "If the data is currently grouped by weeks starting on a Wednesday, I want to change it to group by weeks starting on a Monday, and vice-versa."?

Comment: you hit the nail on the head

Comment: @user3066795 - I updated the answer - it's a bit messy, but it should do what you want.

Comment: Very nice! I follow must of what you did there. Thanks that works perfectly. I'm not familiar with CDATE. I believe I am following what you did with the else IF in the first part. I think I see what  is happening on the second part with the startdate Mod but not sure exactly what Mod is? I know the numbers represent what day of the week we are talking about and when to use which numbers/days for the start date. Just curious what Mod does and Cdate does for future applications. Again thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @user3066795 - (a) `CDate` just forces a value to be a date.  It's similar to `CStr`, `CInt`, `CDbl`, `CCur`, etc.  (b) Dates are just numbers, where 0 is equal to the nonsensical date of 0 January 1900, 1 is 1 January 1900, 2 is 2 January 1900, 60 is the non-existent 29 February 1900 (stupid Excel bug, maintained for backward compatibility), 61 is 1 March 1900, 40756 is 1 August 2011, etc. (c) `x Mod 7` is calculating the remainder after dividing x by 7, so a date that is exactly divisible by 7 is a Saturday, if there is 1 left over then it is a Sunday, 2 is Monday, etc.